# C++: enable function with different return type by type-trait

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I have two functions with different return value, where I want to dynamically change without the usage of macros or inheritance, which function should be used.

In the following example, I want to enable the integer-variant of the function and disable the floating variant:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

constexpr bool int_en = true;

template<std::enable_if_t<int_en, bool> = false>
int test(void) noexcept {
    return 10;
}

template<std::enable_if_t<!int_en, bool> = false>
float test(void) noexcept {
    return 10.;
}

int main(void) {
    std::cout << test();
}
```

I have tried several variations of the program even with std::conditional it is not working:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

constexpr bool int_en = true;
using ret_t = typename std::conditional<int_en, int, float>::type;

template<std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<int, ret_t>::value, bool> = false>
ret_t test(void) noexcept {
    return 10;
}

template<std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<float, ret_t>::value, bool> = false>
ret_t test(void) noexcept {
    return 10.;
}

int main(void) {
    std::cout << test();
}
```

I get always the same error:

```
/usr/include/c++/7/type_traits: In substitution of ‘template<bool _Cond, class _Tp> using enable_if_t = typename std::enable_if::type [with bool _Cond = false; _Tp = bool]’:
tmp5.cpp:11:40:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/7/type_traits:2476:61: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct std::enable_if<false, bool>’
     using enable_if_t = typename enable_if<_Cond, _Tp>::type;
```

What should I do, to get it working?
I am using g++7.3 and C++17.

Comment: Simply [use `constexpr if`](https://wandbox.org/permlink/1hbNsdp0NTsP0BFd) instead of SFINAE.

Comment: You can also [make SFINAE work here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/1EDPSc4iquLFZ2Wx) if you want.

Comment: but why does it work, if I use your approach with the additional template parameter in the sfinae approach?

Comment: SFINAE can work only in the templated context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `enable_if_t` to compute the return type, as in (and it works with c++14, use `enable_if` for c++11):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

constexpr bool int_en = true;

template <bool b = int_en>
std::enable_if_t<b, int>
test(void) noexcept {
    return 10;
}

template <bool b = int_en>
std::enable_if_t<!b, float>
test(void) noexcept {
    return 10.4;
}

int main(void) {
    std::cout << test();
}
```

Comment: yep sorry this one seems to be free of [\[temp.res\]/8.1](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp#res-8.1) violation...

Answer (score 1):

I finally succeeded by using the hint in the comment of Constructor:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

constexpr bool int_en = false;
using ret_t = typename std::conditional<int_en, int, float>::type;

ret_t test(void) noexcept {
    if constexpr(int_en) {
        return 10;
    } else {
        return 10.;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    std::cout << test();
}
```

Comment: Isn't the code ill-formed by breaking the rule [\[temp.res\]/8.1](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp#res-8.1)?

Comment: using `if constexpr` you don't need `ret_t`; you can simply write `auto test(void) noexcept`